# Clean install of 22.04 - no sound, but device is present

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, 22.04

EDIT: UPDATE AT BOTTOM - MORE CHECKS AND TESTS 29-07-2022 13:10

I know there has been issues with losing HDMI, so I spent a few hours reading and trying various things. The same hardware was working with 20.04 the day before yesterday, so I don't think it's a hardware issue.

I did some reading and tried the GRUB edit, but I don't think that is what my problem is - it didn't fix it anyway, but it was the first thing I found when I started reading.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_iommu=on,igfx_off"
```

I updated GRUB and rebooted, got nothing.

So I decided I actually had to think about why it wasn't working...right after I just installed the amdgpu driver, still hoping for a quick fix. Here's the details from

```
$ sudo inxi -F -x

 Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
    vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa gpu: amdgpu resolution: 2560x1440~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon RX 470 Graphics (polaris10 LLVM 13.0.1 DRM
    3.42 5.15.0-43-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.1 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Family HD Audio vendor: Giga.0byte
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
  Device-2: AMD Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]
    vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.1
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-43-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

and here's the info from

```
$ hwinfo --gfxcard

15: PCI 100.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)             
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: VCu0.XsCzxvyR3V3
  Parent ID: vSkL.vfb7IfXn7N2
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:01:00.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Radeon RX 470"
  Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
  Device: pci 0x67df "Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x3411 "Radeon RX 470"
  Revision: 0xcf
  Driver: "amdgpu"
  Driver Modules: "amdgpu"
  Memory Range: 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xe000-0xe0ff (rw)
  Memory Range: 0xdfe00000-0xdfe3ffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 142 (338427 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001002d000067DFsv00001462sd00003411bc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: amdgpu is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe amdgpu"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #12 (PCI bridge)

Primary display adapter: #15
```

Just to be certain:

```
$ pactl info | grep '^Server Name'

Server Name: pulseaudio
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled alsa-base and pulseaudio. Still no joy.

Tried restarting pipewire...

```
$ systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

I ran pavucontrol and it sees both sound devices. When I play an audio or video file, it indicates the levels.

[Super duper high quality video file playing with pavucontrol showing output level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKtWQ.jpg)

Then I checked alsamixer:

ALSA /proc/asound/cards

```
┌────────────────── /proc/asound/cards ───────────────────┐
│ 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH          │
│                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xdff40000 irq 140│
│ 1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI           │
│                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xdfe60000 irq 141 │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

ALSA /proc/sound/pcm

```
┌────────────────────── /proc/asound/pcm ───────────────────────┐
│00-00: ALC1150 Analog : ALC1150 Analog : playback 1 : capture 1│
│00-01: ALC1150 Digital : ALC1150 Digital : playback 1          │
│00-02: ALC1150 Alt Analog : ALC1150 Alt Analog : capture 1     │
│01-03: HDMI 0 : HDMI 0 : playback 1                            │
│01-07: HDMI 1 : HDMI 1 : playback 1                            │
│01-08: HDMI 2 : HDMI 2 : playback 1                            │
│01-09: HDMI 3 : HDMI 3 : playback 1                            │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Levels for Default:1

```
┌─────────────────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.2.6 ───────────────────────────────────┐
│ Card: HDA ATI HDMI                                             F1:  Help               │
│ Chip: ATI R6xx HDMI                                            F2:  System information │
│ View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All                       F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item: S/PDIF                                                   Esc: Exit               │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                            ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐                             │
│                            │OO│     │OO│     │OO│     │OO│                             │
│                            └──┘     └──┘     └──┘     └──┘                             │
│                         < S/PDIF >S/PDIF 1 S/PDIF 2 S/PDIF 3                           │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

None of the above levels will move up from "00"

Aside from running a string and a tin can from my HDMI port, I'm about out of ideas. Any thoughts?

EDIT: UPDATE - MORE CHECKS AND TESTS - 29-07-2022 13:10

More from ALSA

```
$ aplay -l | grep HDMI

card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
```

Trying to play a sound on each of the devices, but got nothing but silence

```
$ aplay -D hw:1,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav

Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1358: Channels count non available


$ aplay -D hw:1,7 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav

Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1358: Channels count non available


$ aplay -D hw:1,8 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav

aplay: main:831: audio open error: Device or resource busy


$ aplay -D hw:1,9 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav

Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1358: Channels count non available
```

I realized that I still had pavucontrol open after I tried this. I closed it and tried to play hw:1,8 again:

```
$ aplay -D hw:1,8 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav

Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1358: Channels count non available
```

Here's the HDMI specific stuff:

```
$ aplay -L | grep HDMI

hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=7
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 1
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=8
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 2
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=9
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 3
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=7
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 1
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=8
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 2
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=9
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 3
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=0
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=1
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=2
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=7
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 1
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=8
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 2
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=9
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 3
usbstream:CARD=HDMI
    HDA ATI HDMI
```

I had already tried with the plughw's too

```
$ aplay -D plughw:1,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav

Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono


$ aplay -D plughw:1,7 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav

Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono


$ aplay -D plughw:1,8 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav

Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono


$ aplay -D plughw:1,9 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav

Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
```

I'm still stumped. Maybe I'm looking at this all wrong, if anyone has any ideas, I'm all ears.

Comment: UPDATE#2 - I installed the Kubuntu desktop and the sound worked with that, so there has to be something wrong with my standard install. At this point I am going to do a back up, and try a fresh install again. Maybe there was something left over from a previous install in my old home folder? I don't know, but I tried pretty much every aside from an exorcism.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Settings > Sound and check which output devices is selected. I'm not trying to insult your intelligence; I'm tossing it out there because every time I've done a clean install of 22.04 desktop on a Raspberry Pi 4, the output device default is headphones. I change it to the built-in digital stereo device, but it defaults to headphones on every reboot even though I don't have headphones. My only output path is HDMI > TV > HDMI-ARC > 5.1 audio. One of several annoyances I've discovered in 22.04.